# Change video quality and bitrate of a video

Tags: html, video, bitrate

can i change the video quality and bitrate of a video(with video tag) on my website using javascript or i have to make some copy of the video with a different quality?
Thanks.

Comment: JavaScript cannot do this.

Comment: Ok! Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a project which compiled ffmpeg to javascript to allow videos be manipulated and converted in the browser:

- https://github.com/bgrins/videoconverter.js

It was originally developed as part of a Node Hackathon, but its not clear whether it is still maintained (see the GitHub activity).

Its worth nothing that it is probably more of an experimental project that a practical one, because of the very large file size.

Comment: Ok i will test it and send you the result!

Answer (score -3):

First ask yourself "is it realy needed to selfhost my video?"
Video plattforms like youtube or vimeo are faster and would bring this options with them.

Comment: The videos aren't on my server but they are on a website and i take the link to mp4 file so they hasn't got an user interface.